# MongoDB times out when I query from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following code results in a time out and I don't have logs to what went wrong. I have no clue when I am getting a time out other than the fact that I have a database issue. I tried several other methods of getting a list of users from Mongo and all of them time out. The code below is what I used. In-fact all mongoose queries are timing out on my app. I've never had this issue with MongoDB before.

```
router.get('/usersList', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    var userMap = {};

    users.forEach(function(user) {
      userMap[user._id] = user;
    });

    res.send(userMap);  
  });
});
```

Comment: You are missing proper error handling in your callback. Add something like if(err) {console.error(err); users= [];} to the top of your callback.

Comment: In addition to what @Deadron said, you probably have not actually connected to MongoDB.  Mongoose will queue queries until it has successfully made a connection.  You should add your connection logic here and confirm that you have MongoDB up and running at the location pointed to by your connection logic.

Comment: Yea I stripped that... I'll add that back and report my findings.

Comment: I used the following error handling logic within the User.find({}, block in a callback

Comment: if (err) return res.status(500).send("<b>DB Failure.</b><br />" + err);

Comment: I did all that and the damn database wasn't even set up right. It was more a case of me not remembering how to set up MongoDB because I hadn't used it in ages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this problem myself. I set up the MongoDB server myself so I killed the server, spun up another and followed the steps listed on DigitalOcean's site because it has been 5 years since I've used MongoDB. I got a much better result with DigitalOcean.com's walkthrough which is here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-centos-7

Once I completed the walkthrough I used their guide to make a production deployment of Node.js: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7

Now I'm testing my API with postman: https://www.getpostman.com/